# Swing: JTextField loses focus when panel repaints

Tags: focus, jtextfield

So I'm working on a game that repaints every frame (If this is a bad way to handle rendering please give me suggestions) and I want to add a text field. Unfortunately repainting causes my textfield to lose focus making it very difficult to type anything into it. That is basically it, if you have any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Apparently I was revalidating the panel every frame also. Changed it so I was only doing that the first frame and got everything working!